# Adding a row to a matrix

Tags: matlab, row, addition

I have a matrix 2x20 from a text file
I want to add a row of ones to that matrix

```
twopts = reshape(textread('input.txt', '%s'),2,20); % 2 by 20
ones_row = ones(1,20);   %1 by 20 of ones

twopts = [twopts;ones_row]
```

Gives me an error:

> "Error using vertcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent."

But the matrix dimensions match... 2x20 and 1x20 to make 3x20

What's wrong with it and how do I fix it?

Comment: try `size(twopts)` and `size(ones_row)` to make sure they are the right size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`twopts` is a cell array of strings and `ones_row` is a matrix, you can't put these together.

Does this do what you want?

```
twopts = reshape(textread('input.txt', '%s'),2,20); % 2 by 20
ones_row = ones(1,20);   %1 by 20 of ones
ones_row = mat2cell(ones_row, 1, ones_row); % convert to cell array

twopts = [twopts;ones_row]
```

Alternatively, if the input data contains numbers, not text, you might want to convert the cell array to a matrix instead:

```
twopts = reshape(textread('input.txt', '%s'),2,20); % 2 by 20
twopts = cellfun(@str2num,twopts);
ones_row = ones(1,20);   %1 by 20 of ones

twopts = [twopts;ones_row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading strings, as you do now, try to simply read numbers (that is - if your data is numbers). Simply omit the `%s` parameter to `textread`:

```
twopts = textread('input.txt');
ones_row = ones(1,20);
twopts = [twopts; ones_row];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your data is numerical, you may try using

> > twopts = importdata('input.txt');
> >
> > ones_row = ones(1,20);
> >
> > twopts = [twopts; ones_row];